# Compile custom Platform in Teamcity 9

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a visual studio solution with non-default configurations and platforms.

I want to build the following combinations:

```
Configuration  Platform
------------   ------
App-Debug    | Emulator
App-Release  | Emulator
App-Debug    | Device
App-Release  | Device
```

As you can see i am not using `x86` or `ARM` or `AnyCPU`  for Platform. I defined my own solution platform.

In Teamcity i define a build step with configuration: `App-Debug`  and Platform: `Emulator.`

But it ignores the Platform setting and automatically sets `x86`. So the build fails. How can i make Teamcity compile for a custom `Platform` property?